# How do I merge changes in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I have used hg clone to get a working copy of a project on a local folder

```
hg clone http://example.com/prj
```

I want to modify some files to meet my needs. For example an original file looks like:

```
int main() {
   cout << "hello";
   return 0;
}
```

So I change that like this:

```
int main() {
   int a = 0;
   cout << "hello";
   return 0;
}
```

Later the main repository changes and looks like this (compare to the first snippet):

```
int main() {
   for (int i=0; i<10; i++ )
      cout << "hello";
   return 0;
}
```

Now when I run

```
hg pull
hg update
```

my change `int a=0;` is lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a crash course of how distributed SCM's work, and moreover **HOW to use them** please read either

- [Joel Spolsky's excellent tutorial](http://hginit.com/01.html)

Or:

- [This illustrated tutorial](http://betterexplained.com/articles/intro-to-distributed-version-control-illustrated/)
- [Mecrurial in daily use](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/mercurial-in-daily-use.html)

Actually, this does *not* happen, if you remember to `hg commit` after you make the change.
You will just have a repository with 2 heads, that you would need to `hg merge` e.g:

```
$ hg pull
pulling from /tmp/remote
searching for changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 1 changesets with 1 changes to 1 files (+1 heads)
(run 'hg heads' to see heads, 'hg merge' to merge)
$ hg merge
  int main() {            |  int main() {            |  int main() {
      int a = 0;          |      for (int i=0; i<10 ;|      cout << "hello";    
      cout << "hello";    |          cout << "hello";|  ------------------------
      return 0;           |      return 0;           |      return 0;
  }                       |  }                       |  }
```

To learn how to use mercurial, please read the [online book](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/)

Comment: You mean I have to run "hg commit" just before "hg pull"?

Comment: After you make your change, yes.

Comment: sorry... Do you mean I have to run 1) hg commit, 2) hg pull, 3) hg merge, 4) hg update?

Comment: Yes. Or more concretely 1. `hg clone`  2. make changes 3. `hg commit` 4. `hg pull` 5. `hg merge` 6. `hg commit` (for the merge) 7. (optional) `hg push`

Comment: You never have to commit before pulling. It is probably a good idea to commit before updating, however when you don’t you shouldn’t lose your changes; the update should merge your working copy changes into the new version. In your particular example there seems to be a conflict, so the conflict will need to be resolved after the update, but still it doesn’t lose your changes.